# How to disable pause and seek bar in embedded media player in HTML

Tags: php, html, django, media-player

I am doing my project on Internet Radio in Django.
I am using Adobe media player in my chrome as a embedded media player to play mp3 in HTML. This media player has PLAY/PAUSE button also SEEK BAR. I want to disable both of them. So when a client connects to the server, he should not be able to manipulate (pause or seek) media stream. What should be done??? Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell that cannot be done.

You need to use an HTML/JavaScript player, like [this one](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/). Then you can modify it with CSS.